Flask session & g with gevent/uwsgi?
I'm running Flask with uWSGI gevent, eg.
uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8000 --gevent 1000 --wsgi-file app.py --callable app ...

where app.py is the Flask application.
I understand that this means that a single CPU thread will run up to 1000 concurrent clients (as coroutines), which makes me wonder:
Is it safe to use flask.session and flask.g is this situation?
Eg. if client A connects to the Flask application and it creates a particular flask.session and flask.g, and, before client A's request is done, client B comes in and the server puts client A on hold to start serving client B, and client B also creates its own flask.session and flask.g, will this work?
Will client A and client B have their own, separate versions of flask.session and flask.g without them getting mixed up, even if the 2 clients are being served concurrently?
